Возможна ли настройка пробелов вокруг вложенного вызова в vs code?
пример вложенного вызова:  alert ( pow(x, n) );
после форматирования на shift+alt+f в vs code: alert (pow(x, n));
можно ли настроить форматирование, чтобы пробелы в скобках сохранялись?

Возможный дубликат вопроса: VS Code сам убирает проставленные мной пробелы
